# Advice needed for an API for reading bits

Tags: c++, bitstring

I found a wonderful project called python-bitstring, and I believe a C++ port could be very helpful in quite some situations (for sure in some projects of mine).

While porting the read/write/patch bytes methods, I didn't get any problems at all; it was as easy as translating Python to C++.

Anyway, now I'm getting to the bits methods and I'm not really sure how to express that functionality.

For example, let's say I want to create a method like:

```
readBits(uint64_t n_bits_to_read, uint64_t n_bits_to_skip = 0) {...}
```

Let's suppose, for the sake of this example, that `this->data` is a chunk of memory (`void *`) holding the entire data from which I'm reading.

So, the method will receive a number of bits to read and an optional number of bits to skip.

```
this->readBits(5, 2);
```

That way I'll be reading bits from position 2 to position 6 inclusive (forget little/big endian for the sake of this example).

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
    ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾
```

I can't return anything smaller than a byte (or can I?), so even if I actually read 5 bits, I'll still be returning 8. But what if I read 14 bits and skip 1? Is there any other way I could return only those bits in some more *useful* way?

I'm thinking about a few common situations, for example:

- Do the first 14 bits match "010101....."
- Do the next 13 bits after skipping 2 match "00011010....."
- Read the first 5 bits and convert them to an int/float
- Read 7 bits after skipping 5 and convert them to an int/float

My question is: what type of data/structure/methods should I return/expose in order to make working with bits easier (or at least easier for the previously described situations).

Comment: You may want a non template version of `std::bitset`

Comment: Also, the name n_bits_to_skip to me sounds like the method would read one bit, skip n_bits_to_skip bits, read another bit, skip another n_bits_to_skip and so on. I suggest you change it to start_from or something similar.